# ¿Por qué no puedo guardar un documento en una carpeta específica usando PHP y JavaScript?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto para cargar un documento de HTML usando JavaScript y guardarlo en una carpeta determinada con PHP. (Estoy usando XAMMP para PHP y todo este proceso incluyendo el sitio web en HTML) Estoy tratando de poner el documento en una carpeta llamada "archivos" usando el método "Publicar" de PHP pero cuando lo envío no hay ningún documento en mi carpeta. No sé si estoy usando la ruta correctamente en PHP o hay algún problema con mi código JavaScript.

Esta es la ruta la cual quiero que se guarde o sea como tal en la carpeta archivos:
C:\xampp\htdocs\Taller\archivos

Este es el código PHP:

```
<?php
    $nombre_temporal = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
    $nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($nombre_temporal, 'archivos/' .$nombre);
?>
```

Código JavaScript

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    let form = document.getElementById('form_subir');

    form.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        subir_archivos(this);
    });
});

function subir_archivos(form){
    let barra_estado = form.children[1].children[0],
        span = barra_estado.children[0],
        botom_cancelar = form.children[2].children[1];

    barra_estado.classList.remove('barra_verde', 'barra_roja');

    //peticion
    let peticion = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //progreso de subida

    peticion.upload.addEventListener("progress", (event) => {
        let porcentaje = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) *100);
        
        console.log(porcentaje);

        barra_estado.style.width = porcentaje+'%';
        span.innerHTML = porcentaje+'%';
    })

    //proceso se haya finalizado
    peticion.addEventListener("load", () => {
        barra_estado.classList.add('barra_verde');
        span.innerHTML = "Proceso Completado";
    });

    //enviar datos

    peticion.open('post', 'subir.php');
    peticion.send(new FormData(form));

    //proceso se haya cancelado
    botom_cancelar.addEventListener("click", () => {
        peticion.abort();
        barra_estado.classList.remove('barra_verde');
        barra_estado.classList.add('barra_roja');
        span.innerHTML = "Proceso Cancelado"

    });
```

[VScode rutas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQDst.png)

[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sivxd.png)

[HTML vista](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWGr9.png)

[Errores en consola](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUaPq.png)

Comment: Hola Luis, bienvendio a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor, traduce tu pregunta, de lo contrario será cerrada. Saludos!

Comment: Necesitamos ver cómo agregas el archivo al `FormData` y de paso, pon un `var_dump($_FILES);` en tu entorno PHP y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: @A.Cedano Me sigue saliendo lo mismo usando el var_dump. No sé si es un problema con la ruta o sino con mi PHP que presentaba problemas en VScode.

Comment: ¿Qué es *lo mismo*? Aquí nos centraremos en tu problema, tratando de ayudarte a resolverlo, sin tener que recorrer el camino que has recorrido, como ver vídeos, etc., no porque sea malo, sino porque es TÚ camino. El código tiene un problema y queremos encontrar ese problema. Sugiero que pongas temporalmente estas tres líneas `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` al inicio de tu archivo `.php` y que nos digas si ves mensajes de error. Si los ves, agrégalos a la pregunta pulsando en [edit].

Comment: @A.Cedano O sea me sigue saliendo lo mismo tal como está en la tercera captura "nada". Y no me saltan errores en el visual poniendo las 3 líneas en PHP. Y sí te agradezco mucho que brindes un poco de tu tiempo para mi duda créeme que te lo agradezco mucho.

Comment: Si pusiste `var_dump($_FILES);` al inicio del archivo `subir.php` deberías ver algo, aunque sea `NULL` o algo, a no ser que tengas problemas con las rutas de archivos. Y, si pones las tres líneas que te sugerí anteriormente, deberás ver en pantalla los mensajes de error. Aunque lo mejor sería que en un futuro aprendas a buscar el log de errores, pues así sabrás con exactitud lo que falla y dónde falla.

Comment: Me sale que no se a detectado ningún problema en el área de trabajo. Y sí es en la ruta de archivos creo el problema. Y voy a tratar recién comienzo con PHP y pues se me dificulta un poco por no decir demasiado.

Comment: No sé, las imágenes no ayudan mucho a entender las rutas, parece que todos los archivos están en una carpeta llamada `js` ¿?  Si el `.html` y el archivo `.js` que tiene la llamada a `XMLHttpRequest` (supongo que es `main.js`) están en la misma carpeta, no tienes que poner el nombre de la carpeta otra vez al incluir el script `.js`. Edita la pregunta poniendo un árbol de directorios/archivos **como texto**. Y de paso revisa la consola del navegador, puede que te informe de archivos no encontrados u otros problemas. El archivo HTML también debería estar como texto en la pregunta.

Comment: Esa era una de las fallas. Solo faltaría solucionar la ruta del PHP y ya estaría. Si, en la carpeta js está el index.html, main.js(el script) y subir.php. También esta la carpeta css que contiene el css del sitio y la carpeta archivos donde quiero que vayan los archivos. La ruta como tal es: Disco local C -> Xammp -> htdocs -> Taller -> js, css y archivos.

Comment: si o si por consola o por php debe salir un warning o error... incluso puede estar en el log... si lo encuentras por favor agregalo a la pregunta

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Ahí edité recién veo los errores.

Comment: Usa un `phpinfo();` y dinos el valor de *User/Group* en **Configuration**.

Comment: es obvio el error que tienes... estas entrando a un HTML desde el filesistem y pretendes que ejecute un php... lo cual es incorrecto... entiendes que para un servidor por ejemplo local la url es http://localhost y que php solo se ejecuta en ese tipo de servidores.

Comment: Dios le bendiga, hermano. Y mil disculpas mi ignorancia recién comienzo con estos temas.

Comment: asumo que saltas a programar sin antes haber tenido un brief sobre como funciona una pagina web y como funcionan los lenguajes de programacion que suas ... suele pasar

Comment: como te decia el error es tipografico ... o de configuracion ... o aun peor de conceptos sobre como funciona cada cosa ... tendrias que evaluar todo eso antes de esperar que tu codigo php se ejecute correctamente ...

Comment: Si, no he usado mucho Xampp y siempre pensé que se podía hacer tanto desde el localhost como desde el index normalmente.

Answer (score 1):

Favor confirma que tienes permiso de escritura en la carpeta donde quieres que el script genere el archivo.

Si te sirve, te adjunto un código de html + php, que se encarga de procesar el archivo y guardarlo donde lo estés necesitando.

Seleccion_Archivo.php

```
         <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="Cargar_Archivo.php">
                <input type="file" name="my_file" id="customFile" />
                <button type="submit" >Subir Archivo</button>
         </form>
```

Carga_Archivo.php

```
         if (($_FILES['my_file']['name']!="")){
            $target_dir = "Carpeta/";
            $file = $_FILES['my_file']['name'];
            $path = pathinfo($file);
            $filename = $path['filename'];
            $ext = $path['extension'];
            $temp_name = $_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'];
            $path_filename_ext = $target_dir.$filename.".".$ext;

             // Check if file already exists
             if (file_exists($path_filename_ext)){
                 echo "Ya existe un archivo con el mismo nombre.";
             }else{
                 move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$path_filename_ext);
                 //echo "Archivo cargado correctamente";
             }
         }
```

Por último si te sirve, podrías añadir lo siguiente, para revisar ciertos valores que se estén enviado correctamente de un archivo a otro.

```
         foreach($_POST as $campo => $valor){
             echo $campo."-------".$valor."<br>";                                     
         }
```

Comment: Sí, tengo todos los permisos de la carpeta. Pero creo que lo único erróneo si es que no hay nada de malo en el script es la ruta del php o algo del php en mi Visualcode.

Comment: Antes de dar una respuesta es importante evaluar todas las alternativas o escenarios que puede estar teniendo el OP, en este caso claramente el error es un poco mas complejo y aunque tu respuesta solucione el problema en el codigo ... es muy probable que no se llegue a ejecutar ...

Comment: con los comentario de daclaracion pude ver que existe otros errores en el entorno de desarrollo.

Comment: Ya me ejecutó todo gracias a Dios. Al fin pude guardar mis archivos en la carpeta deseada. Eso sí tuve que cambiarle la ruta.